# Add second title to navitation drawer

Tags: android, view, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have a navigation drawer and i want to add a second title using code

I know that using this code i can add the first title

```
    View header = View.inflate(this, R.layout.aaaaaaa, null);
    mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

But i do not understand how to add a new second title ...

Example:  "Recent Labels"

[image]

So what i do:

```
    dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.aaaaaaaaaaaaaa,
                dataList);
         View header = View.inflate(this, R.layout.header, null);

        mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);// Then I cannot add second title
 dataList.add(new DrawerItem("One ",R.drawable.aa));
 dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Two",R.drawable.aa));
//How to add new title????
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Navigation Drawer : add headers in listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16984027/navigation-drawer-add-headers-in-listview)

Comment: still i do not understand how to achieve this using code

Comment: Refer [this](http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/08/section-header-listview-in-android.html).

Answer (score 0):

That's nothing but a sectioned listview by defining a custom adapter. Learn and implement from [ListView Tips & Tricks #2: Sectioning Your ListView](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/07/05/listview-tips-tricks-2-section-your-listview/)