# How to save changes in ArrayList when switching ListFragment using Drawer ListView

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I have a Drawer Listview with items Fruits, Veggies, Meat. Each has a class that extends ListFragment. I also created a Product class for my ArrayList and ArrayAdapter. But everytime i switch between ListFragment and switch back, the changes I did also reset and not saved.

Here is my Current codes:

product_adapter.java

```
//imports ....

public class product_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<product> {

    public product_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<product> prod) {
        super(context, 0, prod);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final product products = getItem(position);

        // Some Codes for Instantiation and LayoutInflater


        itemAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                products.itemQuantity ++;
                viewHolder.itemQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(products.getItemQuantity()));
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Fruit.java

```
public class Fruit extends ListFragment {

    public ArrayList<product> products;
    public product_adapter productAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        products = new ArrayList<product>();

        products.add(new product("Apple", 18.00 /*Price*/, 0 /*Quantity*/));
        products.add(new product("Orange", 16.00 /*Price*/, 0 /*Quantity*/));

        productAdapter = new product_adapter(getActivity(),products);

        setListAdapter(productAdapter);
    }
}
```

Veggies and Meat Class is constructed the same way as the Fruit class

MainActivity with the ListView

```
//Some codes here for the creating ListView
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.categoryView);
        listView.setAdapter(new category_adapter(this, categories));
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerView);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                ListFragment listFragment = null;
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        listFragment = new Fruit();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        listFragment = new Veggies();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        listFragment = new Meat();
                        break;
                }

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.itemLayout,listFragment).commit();
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            }
        });
```

Comment: you mean on pressing backbutton??

Comment: sry about that i forgot to mention that it is a drawer listview

Comment: you need expandable list on drawer to categorise your products??

Comment: i ddnt use expandable listview on drawer, i just used listview for the drawer and used onitemclicklistener to open the listfragments. ill try your suggestion and use expandable listview rather than using listview and listfragment.

Answer (score 0):

@mark.jon Here is the code implemented by me for producing categorised list on drawer using expandable list.. Hope this fulfills your needs.. [Default Navigation Drawer View to ExpandableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38765790/default-navigation-drawer-view-to-expandablelistview/38767046#38767046)