# How to get Group and Child positions from Multilevel ExpandableListview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Hi I have requirement to show items in multilevel expandable listview and for this i searched in google and found below code it's working fine

But how can i find each level Group and Child positions can some one help me please..

### Activity:-

```
public class SampleActivity extends ActivityBase {

    ExpandableListView explvlist;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setUpBaseLayout(R.layout.activity_expandable);
        explvlist = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.ParentLevel);
        explvlist.setAdapter(new ParentLevel());
    }

    public class ParentLevel extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {
            return arg1;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                                 boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            CustExpListview SecondLevelexplv = new CustExpListview(SampleActivity.this);
            SecondLevelexplv.setAdapter(new SecondLevelAdapter());
            SecondLevelexplv.setGroupIndicator(null);

            return SecondLevelexplv;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                                 View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(SampleActivity.this);
            tv.setText("->FirstLevel");
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tv.setTextSize(20);
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            tv.setPadding(10, 7, 7, 7);

            return tv;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class CustExpListview extends ExpandableListView {

        int intGroupPosition, intChildPosition, intGroupid;

        public CustExpListview(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(960,
                    MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(600,
                    MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }


    public class SecondLevelAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                                 boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(SampleActivity.this);
            tv.setText("child");
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tv.setTextSize(20);
            tv.setPadding(15, 5, 5, 5);
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            tv.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

            return tv;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                                 View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(SampleActivity.this);
            tv.setText("-->Second Level");
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tv.setTextSize(20);
            tv.setPadding(12, 7, 7, 7);
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

            return tv;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

### xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/ParentLevel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

set these callbacks for your expandable list. This is my working example in which i have implemented Expandable list view on navigation drawer.. And you can just refer same example to populate it activity also https://stackoverflow.com/a/38767046/6350239

```
   expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, long id) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
        // Listview Group expanded listener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Listview Group collasped listener
        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        // Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Temporary code:

                // till here
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                + " : "
                                + listDataChild.get(
                                listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });}
```

Comment: i have 3 levels but your saying for 2 levels

Comment: check out the link i have mentioned for one of my stack overflow answer.. see if that meets your requirement for expandable list view.. and the same link has the complete working code as well

Comment: i have multilevel Expandable Listview not single level

Comment: you mean first level child will have children as well ??

Comment: I post image also i want that Second level and child level group and Child positions please see once

Comment: Your parent level expandable list view is returning another Expandable list view in getChildview which should have a click listener to listen to second level clicks..

Comment: do you have any idea for finding position if know please post some code

Comment: I do not have working code for same but I need to run this code and add listeners in order to make sure it works as expected... try to add click listeners for your child view in parent adapter and see if u r getting postions

Comment: can u please check this code in ur system and can u please give me solution because i already tried my level best