# Set two levels in a drawerlayout

Tags: android

I'm developing an app which uses a drawer layout. I need it to have 2 levels. I can't find anywhere how to do this.

For instance, the menu would look like this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pM7Q.png

Is there a way to achieve this with a drawer Layout and Navigation View ?

Comment: Where is the image ?

Comment: Sorry, it's edited.

Comment: you have to use ExpandableListView in Drawer layout.

Comment: Use group to add items

Comment: Group doesn't create levels and I don't want the items to be expandable.

Comment: This question is already answeredf [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38765790/default-navigation-drawer-view-to-expandablelistview)
you can check .