# Inflating a custom view below header view in Navigation view android

Tags: android, android-layout, navigationview, android-navigationview

I have a DrawerLayout with NavigationView as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_dynamic_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <include layout="@layout/navigation_drawer_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In NavigationView, a header view is inflated dynamically as shown below.

```
View headerView = getCustomHeaderView(navigationView);
        if (headerView != null) {
            navigationView.addHeaderView(headerView);
        }
```

Another layout is included in the NavigationView which contains an ExpandableListView. I need to place this layout just below the inflated headerView. I achieved this by dynamically getting the height of the headerView and setting the same as "marginTop" property to the included layout. But this fails(both views overlaps) if the headerView doesnt have a static height(if wrap_content).
How can I set the included layout just below the headerView in NavigationView in an effective way. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default Navigation Drawer View to ExpandableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38765790/default-navigation-drawer-view-to-expandablelistview)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Thats what i did. But my requirement was to dynamically get the header view height of the layout with height wrap_content. I achieved that using onWindowFocusChanged method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is as simple as that. Just get the height of the dynamic header view(with height wrap_content) using the method, onWindowFocusChanged and set it as the margin_top attribute to the included layout in NavigationView.

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (navigationView.getHeaderView(0) != null) {
            int headerHeight = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).getHeight();
            RelativeLayout navigationParentView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.navigation_parent_view);
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            params.setMargins(0,headerHeight,0,0);
            navigationParentView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    }
```